# Get the creation time of an access key from AWS API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Is there a function in boto that returns the creation time of access key?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe there is any way to get that info.  For root AWS accounts, there is very little available in the way of API access.  But even for IAM users the API doesn't provide any way to get a timestamp for when the credentials were created.  You can list the available credentials via the [ListAccessKeys](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccessKeys.html) API call but the output of that request does not return the creation date/time.

Temporary credentials created via the [STS service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) include an expiration timestamp and you could probably infer a creation time from that if you know what duration was associated at the time the credentials were created.

Comment: Will get_all_access_keys from boto give me some info?

Comment: It will give you all of the data returned by the [IAM API Call](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_ListAccessKeys.html) which is the username, the access key, and the status.  Unfortunately, no creation data information is returned by the service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. We can find out the time of creation of the Access Keys along with all the Access keys.

```
user=conn.get_all_users()

usr_response=user['list_users_response']['list_users_result']["users"]

for user_name in usr_response:
     k=user_name['user_name']
     user_a_key=conn.get_all_access_keys(k)
     for a_key in user_a_key['list_access_keys_response']['list_access_keys_result']['access_key_metadata']:
        if(a_key['status']=='Active'):
            print k, '->', a_key['access_key_id'], "created on",a_key['create_date']
```